# Detailed Impact view

Tags: feature-request, people-reached

There is a widget where I can see how much impact all my answers have.
[image]

I think it will be helpful if there is a detailed view for it, so that I can see which pages have how much impact.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but on Meta, voting works differently, especially for feature request. People downvote because they don't agree, not because it's a bad post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the impact is only a *rough estimate*, it doesn't make much sense to have a breakdown. If you do want one, you can use SEDE to find this out. @rene has already done this in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264626/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ok. can you then please delete your answer. After this i can delete the question

Comment: Why should he delete his useful answer to your useful question? Why delete the question at all, @Jens ?

Comment: @oded Why you think it is a usefull question with 4 downvotes in 6 minutes?

Comment: Do you understand how downvoting works here on meta? That people disagree with the question doesn't make it any less useful, @Jens

Comment: @Oded ok. I think in the stackoverflow way ;). Sorry for that

Comment: No worries, @Jens - sometimes people forget meta is different (for example - that rep doesn't change here...)

Comment: @Jens: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) is some information about the voting culture here.